# how to remove error of "error: cannot find symbol holder.name.setText(personNames.get(position))"

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to run the code given in google drive the link is as follow: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dX0aPWgxs_LvXWFsBzEKdxuWV1QHogBP?usp=sharing)

I am using 4.1.2 android version IED, but from the following code I am getting error as:

error: cannot find symbol holder.name.setText(personNames.get(position));
symbol:   variable name
location: variable holder of type ViewHolder

In the section of the code of CustomAdapter.java file given below from the error is appearing. How could we resolve it?

```
package com.example.recyclerviewexample;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList personNames;
    ArrayList personImages;
    Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList personNames, ArrayList personImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personNames = personNames;
        this.personImages = personImages;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // set the data in items
        holder.name.setText(personNames.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageResource(personImages.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // open another activity on item click
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", personImages.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personNames.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // init the item view's
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewHolder class is MyViewHolder but you bind it with RecylerView.ViewHolder change override methods according to viewHolder class like CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder